# Launch the app and display NFC tag info by only one touch with phonegap cordova

Tags: android, cordova, nfc

I am trying to write an application on Android that can read and display information of a NFC tag, using phonegap. 
The scenario as the following:

- 0.The smartphone and the NFC tag touch each other
- 1.My application is launched automatically
- 2.Display NFC tag info on the app screen

The 1. task can be done by adding filter into manifest.xml file.

Is it possible to do 2. task without touching NFC tag one more time, after the application launched?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to write to tags on NFC

1. Info that you need to read
2. your application package name.

In Manifest add filters to your activity

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true" />
```

In NfcReader.java

```
    public String getNfcData(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)) {
        Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

        if (parcelables != null && parcelables.length > 0) {
            String data = readTextFromMessage((NdefMessage) parcelables[0]);
            return data;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot Read From Tag.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return "No NDEF messages found!";
        }
    }
    return "";
```

### }

```
    String readTextFromMessage(NdefMessage ndefMessage) {

    NdefRecord[] ndefRecords = ndefMessage.getRecords();

    if (ndefRecords != null && ndefRecords.length > 0) {

        NdefRecord ndefRecord = ndefRecords[0];

        String tagContent = getTextFromNdefRecord(ndefRecord);


        return tagContent;

    } else {
        return "No NDEF records found!";
    }
```

### }

```
      public String getTextFromNdefRecord(NdefRecord ndefRecord) {
    String tagContent = null;
    try {
        byte[] payload = ndefRecord.getPayload();
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
        int languageSize = payload[0] & 0063;
        tagContent = new String(payload, languageSize + 1,
                payload.length - languageSize - 1, textEncoding);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("getTextFromNdefRecord", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    Log.e("log", "getTextFromNdefRecord");
    return tagContent;
}
```

---

In your Main Activity

```
     protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    if (getIntent().hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)) {
        String NfcID = nfcReader.getNfcID(getIntent());
        String tagData = nfcReader.getNfcData(getIntent());
        String nfcPackage = nfcReader.readNfcPackage(getIntent());

        Log.d(Const.TAG, "NFCID: " + NfcID);
        Log.d(Const.TAG, "Data: " + tagData);
        Log.d(Const.TAG, "package Name: " + nfcPackage);

        if (nfcPackage.equals(Const.packageName)) {
            prefs.edit().putString(Const.VAN_NUMBER_PREF, tagData).commit();
            vanNumberTxt.setText("Van #: " + tagData);
            Tools.vibrator(this);
            toggleButton.setChecked(true);
        } else finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank @Davit Avetisyan for detail code

So, the keys to get tag info is extracting from intent

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
String myTagId = bytesToHexString(tag.getId());

Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
NdefMessage[] msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];

NdefRecord[] records = msgs[i].getRecords();

byte[] payload = records[j].getPayload();
```